# How to use regex in not ASCII strings?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I have this code:

```
opendir(DIR, ".");
while (readdir DIR) {
  print $1, "\n" if $_ =~ /(\w+)/i;
}
```

It gets only ASCII strings of course. How can I get another non ASCII strings in output with using regexp?

**UPD**

For example if in "." directory there are two files `file` and `другойфайл`. So when I run this script I get only `file` in the output but I'd like to get another file with non English name `другойфайл`

Comment: Of course, what? Why does it only get ASCII strings?

Comment: `\w+` is alphanumeric characters. You can get negate the character class with `\W+`.

Comment: Well I would like to parse not only English file name. I've written about it in UPD.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: Don't use bareword directory handles. Don't ignore errors from `opendir`. `$_ =~` is redundant. The `i` on your regex is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code seems to work:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Encode qw(decode);

my $dir = $ARGV[0] || '.';
opendir my $dh, $dir  or die "$0: $dir: $!\n";
while (readdir $dh) {
    $_ = decode 'UTF-8', $_;
    print $1, "\n" if /(\w+)/;
}
```

This assumes your file system stores names in UTF-8, of course.

Output:

```
file
другойфайл
```

Comment: It's works. Thank you. `use encoding('utf8');` is needed add to file in order to avoid these messages `Wide character in print at`.

Comment: Don't use "encoding". Use `use open ':std', ':utf8';`